# Adding custom parameter in vue2-dropzone event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dropzone.js

I'm using [vue2-dropzone](https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/docs/dist) which exposes a list of [events](https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/docs/dist/#/events) E.g. For when the file transfer is complete.

In my SFC (single file component), I use 2 of these dropzone components to differentiate different uploads. I use the event

```
vdropzone-upload-progress(file, progress, bytesSent)
```

to display progress for each dropzone separately outside the dropzone.

```
<vue-dropzone @vdropzone-upload-progress="progress($event, 'from_dz1')" ref="myVueDropzone" id="dz1" :options="dropzoneOptions"></vue-dropzone>
<vue-dropzone @vdropzone-upload-progress="progress($event, 'from_dz2')" ref="myVueDropzone" id="dz2" :options="dropzoneOptions"></vue-dropzone>
```

When I do that, in my `progress` method I am only able to get the `file` object and my custom parameter `from_dz1` and `from_dz2` because it matches the first position of the original.

Is there anyway I can do `@vdropzone-upload-progress="progress(file, progress, bytesSent, 'from_dz1')"` and in my `progress` method, I do

```
progress: function (file, progress, bytesSent, origin) {
  console.log(file.name, 'from', origin, progress, '% done')
}
```

and be able to get all 4 arguments?

A workaround I thought of was to have 3 methods, progress, progress1, and progress2 where both progress1 and 2 would call progress with the additional 'from_dz1' string but it doesn't seem like a scalable idea. If I used more than 1 event I'll end up with many more methods and likewise if I have more dropzones I'll end up with even more methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
<vue-dropzone @vdropzone-upload-progress="(file, progress, bytesSent) => progress(file, progress, bytesSent, 'from_dz1')" ref="myVueDropzone" id="dz1" :options="dropzoneOptions"></vue-dropzone>
```

Comment: Thank you Tuan. It worked. The only part that tripped me up was naming the method `progress` which didn't work because one of the parameters is also named `progress`. Renamed to `show_progress` and it worked flawlessly. This is considered calling the `show_progress` method in an inline handler?

Comment: @celerius I don't really understand your question. Could you please rephrase it?